# Configuration file no password

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, root

I run a localhost server for MySQL and PHP, in the phpMyAdmin I get the message on pink background:

"Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the MySQL privileged default account.
Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a
password for user 'root'."

Can anybody please tell me about the risks?
Are there any?
Like what?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

By default say xampp use no password. Mamp uses password root by default. This wil do no harm if you only work locally. If you want to set a password anyway than look at the documentation depends on the software you are using.